# How do I change the fill color of svg file in pixate framework

Tags: ios, svg, ios7, uibutton, pixate

i'm working on a iOS 7 project, iPhone Retina(4-inch),  where I have an UIButton. I'm using Pixate  framework 2.0.1 for styling my UI component. I have added a user defined runtime attribute to my UIButton,
key path: 'styleId'
type: string
value: 'big-magnify-btn'

In my default.css I have defined the following.

## big-magnify-btn {

`background-image: url(button-scan.svg);`
}
/* Black magnify image */

When I run my application the button shows up in black, how do I do if I want to change the fill color in my default.css class #big-magnify-btn ???? I want my image in a different color.

All kind of help is appreciated

Here is the button-scan.svg
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ks1vym66bfjwbtw/button-scan.svg

Comment: Adjust the fill colour in button-scan.svg so it's the colour you want. You can't change the colour of a background image externally.

Comment: OK thanx for your reply, but I wonder how come when I use same button-scan.svg in a UIBarButtonItem as followed its show up in white??

#magnify icon {
    background-image: url(button-scan.svg);
    background-size: 25;   
}

Cheers!

Comment: Difficult to say since you haven't shown us button-scan.svg

Comment: How can I add the file here Robert Longson?

Comment: Edit your question and add it.